# Advice regarding wrapping text inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a contact card style layout, with a photo and text next to it, as demonstrated in this fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7pWv/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contact-card">
        <div class="photo"></div>

        <div class="details">
            <span class="name">My Name</span>
            <span class="description">This is some really long text that should wrap nicely when things all work OK</span>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>    

    <div class="contact-card">
        <div class="photo"></div>

        <div class="details">
            <span class="name">My Name 2</span>
            <span class="description">Short description</span>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {    
    width: 350px;
}

.contact-card {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.contact-card .photo {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tan;
    margin: 10px;
}

.contact-card .details {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.contact-card .name {
    display: block; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 1em;
}

.contact-card .description {
    display: block; 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
    color: silver; 
    line-height: 1em;
    white-space: normal;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

As you can see from running the fiddle, when the text is really long, it does wrap eventually, based upon my white-space setting, but it exceeds the size of the contact card before doing so.  I could put a right margin of 90px on the "description" class to keep the text within the bounds (which works), but I can't help but feel this is wrong.  I'd like it to naturally want to stay within its parent's bounds, but can't think of the best way to achieve that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest just don't use `inline-block` for this. You don't want the `.detail` element overflow on it's parent element. Because you already floated your photo, you can just place the element next to the photo element.

Note that you should use *padding when you want space inside the element* and use *margin when you want it outside of the element.*

There is no need for `white-space: nowrap;` as you floated the photo.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7pWv/4/)**

*The only thing i changed is the use of padding and margin and removed the `white-space` .*

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer best suits my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider making these changes:

```
.contact-card {
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact-card .details {
    display: block; 
}
```

This will keep each card displaying inline while keeping the text of the card inside the block without specifying a margin.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't quite work when put into my updated fiddle to demonstrate my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a tricky one, as I don't know what uses you'll be putting this in, but I'd probably do it with these changes.

Get rid of

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

It's not needed if you make a simple addition like:

```
.contact-card {
    float:left;
}
```

Then change `.contact-card .details` to this:

```
.contact-card .details {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

That should give you the `"The width of the details element should really be dictated by the parent."` behaviour you're after

http://jsfiddle.net/L7pWv/6/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite fill out my example enough to make it clearer. I updated my fiddle accordingly here: http://jsfiddle.net/L7pWv/5/. Basically the list items should stack on top of one another in a vertical list.  Your solution doesn't quite meet those needs - sorry about that.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson ah, thats why you'd need the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` or to just add `clear:both;` to `.contact-card`

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.contact-card .details {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   width:70%;
```

}

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7pWv/2/

Comment: Sorry, not quite what I'm after. The width of the details element should really be dictated by the parent.  I used a fixed width for the container for my example, but in my actual implementation I don't have this - the container width is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I didn't want to set a width on the details at all.